# Stray voltage on all earthed and unearthed objects

Tags: voltage

We installed an earth mat on a property to eliminate voltage on earthed and unearthed objects on the property. But after installation it was still there. Surprisingly if you measure voltage between two point on the ground itself , the tester reads 10 v AC at 1 meter distance and 80 v AC at about 6 meter distance . All metal objects installed in the buildings even window frames have voltage on them.
Earth mat is 1 meter by one meter and two meters deep , it is connected on the main earth of the property at the supply box through means of a ferrule.

Residents complained to us about getting shocked when touch metal objects on property , on inspection we found that all over the property the earth had 80v ac, we combined earth and neutral to eliminate the voltage but it did not work hence we installed the earth mat.

After installation of earth mat we found the voltage had stil not gone away, we further investigated and found between the ground and metal objects such as the window frames had voltage on them. We also put the probes of the tester on two points on the ground and again found a varied voltage at different distances. There is a 11 k power line across the road but it is common all over the country and at other locations we did not have this problem, at the power line we dit however see the earth mat for the transformer is not connected.

Also when switching main power supply of on municipal side the voltage on earth does not go away. Hope this extra information helps.

Comment: An earth mat does not equipotentially bond structures.

Comment: The structures are brick structures and the voltage stays even if main power supply to property is disconnected

Comment: You are building under/over high voltage power lines?

Comment: The 11 k power line is across the road where the transformer is. Only the property's supplied by this transformer has the voltage problem

Comment: "*... **we combined earth and neutral to eliminate the voltage** ...*". Oh-oh! Where in the building power circuit did you do this? You have no location information in your user profile so we don't know what regulations apply in your country but what you have done may be very dangerous and illegal.

Comment: You might consider hiring an electrician

Comment: It is not illegal it is a TNC system. Higher protection and gives a higher predictable uitcome to circuit breakers or fuses. And here is my country (South Africa ) it is automatically done at transformer and then inside the house it is split into neutral and earth. And we did it at the main supply box

Answer (score 2):

My suspicion would be a broken or high-resistance neutral somewhere in a supply cable.  That would divert return currents through the earth connection instead.  Since earth connections are never zero resistance, that could produce a significant voltage on the earth.  If the neutral at your installation is significantly far from 0V, then that's probably it.

If you can, measure all voltages relative to an independent earth rod, hammered into the ground as far as possible away from any other earth rods or mats.

Comment: High impedance neutral will only cause earth currents if the neutral is broken between the supply earth and the building earth rod. OP hasn't said what his reference point is though so your second paragraph is a good way of testing - but not with a high-Z meter.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a digital meter for this then you may be measuring stray electric field due to the meter's high impedance, typically 10 MΩ.

Try putting a 1k to 10k resistor across the meter close to the terminals or at the end of the standard probes if you are using wire to extend the probes. This will present more of a load and may solve the problem.

If not then please edit your question to supply details on the "earth mat", link to a datasheet and explain how you connected the mat to mains or building earth.

Comment: I have added more details to my question hope it helps